# Set static resource in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource, app.xaml

I have a few styles in my `App.xaml` file:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleBlue" Color="#FF4B77BE"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleRed" Color="#FFF64747"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleOrange" Color="#FFF89406"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleGreen" Color="#FF1BBC9B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleYellow" Color="#FFF9BF3B"/>

<Style x:Key="stackpanelBackground" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource styleBlue}"/>
</Style>
```

I want to change the `BackgroundProperty` in the code of my `mainpage.xaml.cs`.

I tried using this:

```
Style style = Application.Current.Resources["stackpanelBackground"] as Style;          
style.Setters.SetValue(StackPanel.BackgroundProperty, "{StaticResource styleRed}");
```

But I get a catastrophic failure exception. I think it  has to do with `{StaticResource styleRed}`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A [`StaticResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) is static. You can't change them once the application has compiled.

For this purpose, there is [`DynamicResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx):

> A **DynamicResource** will create a temporary expression during the initial compilation and thus defer lookup for resources until the requested resource value is actually required in order to construct an object.

Also note that you can find the reference to the other resource better using [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try something like this (full working sample):

In `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Color R="255" x:Key="styleRed" />
    <Style x:Key="abc" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
Style style = this.FindResource("abc") as Style;
var r = this.FindResource("styleRed");

foreach (Setter s in style.Setters)
{
    if (s.Property == StackPanel.BackgroundProperty)
    {
        s.Value = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using DynamicResource but it says "The name "DynamicResource" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"."

Comment: @ArnVanhoutte: See the edit. Does this help? Any information in the `Output` pane in Visual Studio when you run the project?

Comment: I tried to use the method in your edit, but it didn't work. It can't resolve FindResource

Comment: @ArnVanhoutte: Try `Application.FindResource` then.

Comment: Tried it too. And also App.FindResource. Output just show that it failed to build. Error is this: 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'FindResource'

Comment: Try to place that code in the `Window.xaml.cs` class.

Comment: I don't have that class. It is a Windows Phone app. There is by default an App.xaml (with App.xaml.cs) and MainPage.xaml (with MainPage.xaml.cs)

Comment: In `App.xaml.cs` then?

Comment: Same problem. I think that there is no FindResource for windows phone. That's why I used Application.Current.Resources

Comment: Okay. If you change that in the code, and use the XAML I provided, does it work then?

Comment: Like this: 
Style style = App.Current.Resources["stackpanelBackground"] as Style;
style.Setters.SetValue(StackPanel.BackgroundProperty, App.Current.Resources["styleRed"]);

I get the same exception then as in the original post.

Comment: Any info in the Output Window?

Comment: "A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
The program '[5328] AgHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)."

Comment: Can you put a `try catch` around it and check the exception?

Comment: the Exception Message is "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"

Comment: Any inner exceptions? Call stack?

Comment: No not really. Just that. I can send you the code if you want

Comment: @ArnVanhoutte: I switched from testing this in a Desktop app to WP. It breaks there indeed. Here it says: "Access is denied" on setting the property. Maybe this is not allowed?

Comment: I don't get that access is denied error. Could be that it is not allowed though.

Answer (score 12):

Why are you modifying the Style instead of setting the `Background`-Property of your targeted `StackPanel` directly? Since a 'Local value' has a higher precedence than 'Style setters' the value that you write into `Background` from code behind would be used

Means:

(1) Give a name to your stackpanel `x:Name="spBla"`

(2) Assign the Brush to the `Background` of `spBla` ( something like `spBla.Background=Application.Current.Resources["styleRed"] as SolidColorBrush;` )

You can learn more about value precedence here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because I have a lot of stackpanels in my different views. So instead of changing them all, I can just assign the ones I want to change to a specific style and then changing that style.

Answer (score 1):

**xaml** resource

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GrayBlueGardientBrush"  
                                StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="DarkCyan" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCCCFF" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkCyan" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
```

CS

```cs
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var r = this.FindResource("GrayBlueGardientBrush");
        (sender as Button).Background = r as LinearGradientBrush;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to set up a style that allows you to only change specific stackpanels, so you don't have to set them all. Give this suggestion a try (note: it is a suggestion and I have not tested it, but hopefully it is in the right direction)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleBlue" Color="#FF4B77BE"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleRed" Color="#FFF64747"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleOrange" Color="#FFF89406"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleGreen" Color="#FF1BBC9B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="styleYellow" Color="#FFF9BF3B"/>

<Style x:Key="stackpanelBackground" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, FallbackValue={StaticResource styleBlue}}"/>
</Style>
```

Or try TemplateBinding instead of Binding, like I said it is a suggestion and I haven't tested it. This would give you a binding for the background, and a fallback value for a stackpanel that you haven't set a background color for. Let me know how or if this works for you :)